# I am not getting the expected output for my code

Tags: python, csv

I will try to simplify this is as much as possible , My code is designed for a user to enter multiple products from a data base using a barcode , resulting in my program outputting in the name of the products they ordered and the total price of the products.

However my expected output of the code when it is first run is

```
GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number: "))
            return GTIN # Breaks the loop and returns the value
        except:
            print ("Oops! That was not a valid number.  Try again")
```

However this code is first run at the end of the code as the starting line for some reason.

```
continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
if continue_shopping != 0 and continue_shopping != 1:
    print("make sure you enter a valid number")
```

I would appreciate any helpful input or criticism for my code.

If you are interested here is the code as an entity on its own. Thank you for any help

```
import csv 
import locale
from decimal import *
total_price = []

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
def read_csv_file():
    global total_price
    """ reads csv data and appends each row to list """
    csv_data = []
    with open("task2.csv") as csvfile:
         spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
         for row in spamreader:
             csv_data.append(row)
    return csv_data


def get_user_input():
    global total_price
    """ get input from user """
    while True:
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number: "))
            return GTIN # Breaks the loop and returns the value
        except:
            print ("Oops! That was not a valid number.  Try again")


def search_user_input(product_data):
    global total_price
    repeat=""
    # Pass the csv data as an argument
    """ search csv data for string """
    keep_searching = True

    while keep_searching:
        gtin = get_user_input()
        for row in product_data:
            if row[0] == str(gtin):
                product = row[1]
                price = round(float(row[2]),2)
                return(product, price)
        while True:
            try:
                repeat = input("not in there? search again? If so (y), else press enter to continue")
                break
            except:
                print("please make sure you enter a valid string") 
        if repeat != 'y':
            keep_searching = False 
            return None 


def quantity():
    fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(fileOne)
    global total_price
    product_data = read_csv_file()
    matches = search_user_input(product_data)
    if matches: # Will not be True if search_user_input returned None
        print("apple")
        product, price = matches[0], matches[1]

        order = int(input("How much of {} do you want?".format(product)))
        TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2
        subt = order * pricea
        subtotal = Decimal(subt).quantize(TWOPLACES)
        values = [str(product), str(price), str(subtotal)]
        print('values are ',values)
        writer.writerows((values,))
        total_price.append(order * price)

continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
if continue_shopping != 0 and continue_shopping != 1:
    print("make sure you enter a valid number")
    if (continue_shopping == 0):
        fileOne.close()
        fileTwo = open("receipt.csv" , "r")
        reader = csv.reader(fileTwo)
        for row in reader:
            if row != None:
                print(row)
    elif continue_shopping==1:
        quantity()
quantity()
```

Comment: *"However this code is first run at the end of the code as the starting line for some reason."* Well, of course it is. It's the first statement (apart from imports) that is not part of a function definition. You don't actually *call* the functions that you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a function (that's what def does), it won't do anything until you instantiate the function. so, for instance, if you want to run the read_csv_file() function before you do ask whether the person is done shopping, you have to do this. (or something similar)

```
#all your functions are above this snippet.

read_csv_file()

continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much kind sir